# Air - Allow app installation based on date

Tags: date, air, installation

I need to find a way that allows the installation of an Adobe Air based app only if the current date is within this year.
How can that be done?

Edit: It's for an Adobe Air for Windows app. I will publish the Air app as a Windows Installer .exe.

Comment: Adobe Air for Windows. I will publish the Air app as a Windows Installer .exe.

Answer (score 0):

The p12 certificate you add to your AIR app contains the start date and end date used to determine whether the app can be installed. These dates are set by the certificate authority you choose (VeriSign, Thawte...).

Flash Builder and Flash CS allow you to create a self-signed certificate, but they don't allow you to set the start and end dates (they default to 5 years from the current date).

If you want to create a self-signed certificate and specify the end date yourself, you could do it using the [AIR Developer Tool (ADT)](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/air/build/WS901d38e593cd1bac1e63e3d128fc240122-7ffc.html). ADT accepts an optional  "-validityPeriod" flag with which you specify a number of years.